# Redhat 7.6 on 4TB machine: Unable to use more than 1TB

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, memory

We have a 4-CPU/72-core machine with 4TB memory running Redhat 7.6.

`/proc/cmdline` shows:

`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 ... ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg00/lswap nomodeset rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

We have been unable to allocate more than 1TB of memory on this machine when running jobs. I've been able to reproduce this by allocating memory using `stress-ng`. For example here is the status now:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.9T        279G        2.2T         34G        1.4T        3.6T
Swap:          127G        849M        127G
```

and when I try to use stress-ng to allocate memory to get above 1TB used, I get failures. This command works fine:

```
stress-ng -m 60 --vm-bytes 700G -t 180s
```

and I see memory max out at about 980GB. But if I allocate a little more I get an mmap failure.

```
stress-ng -m 60 --vm-bytes 800G -t 180s
stress-ng: info:  [90100] dispatching hogs: 60 vm
stress-ng: error: [90457] stress-ng-vm: gave up trying to mmap, no available memory
```

And `free` shows usage topping out at 1TB. We've never been able to get above 1TB used.

Is there a kernel configuration or something else we should look at that could be limiting user memory to 1.0TB? Over time the `buff/cache` value grows to 3.0T and never gets released, presumably because the kernel isn't allowing user processes to dip into that well.

Comment: Holy cow! Three *terabytes* of memory and *72* cores? That's no desktop.

Comment: Can you try with 1 thread rather than 60 threads, and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Good idea; I was seeing similar results with one thread. The reason I moved to 60 threads was so I could count how many threads failed, and see how much was successfully allocated before failure.